# ACF - get fields from group

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

i have been using this code to get all fields from a specific group:

```
<?php
$GroupOrPostSlug = 'acf_specialgroup';
//or insert the ID of your fields Group.
$groupID='';



global $wpdb;
if (empty($groupID))
{$groupID = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name =  '$GroupOrPostSlug' ");}
if (empty($groupID))
{$groupID = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title =  '$GroupOrPostSlug' ");}

$custom_field_keys = get_post_custom_keys($groupID);
foreach ( $custom_field_keys as $key => $fieldkey )
{
    if (stristr($fieldkey,'field_'))
    {
        //echo $key . " => " . $fieldkey . "<br />";
        //echo $field['label'] . ': ' . $field['value'];
        //echo $fieldkey . "<br />";
        $field = get_field_object($fieldkey, $groupID);
        echo $field['label'];

    }
}
?>
```

but it displays only fields' names. doesnt there exist a simple hook/function, something like this: `get_all_fields_from_group($id)`

Answer (score 10):

Thank you so much for your post, I spent half day to figure out how to get field names by their group.

If you have field names, you can easily get their values: get_field($field['name']);

**EXAMPLE HOW TO GET IMAGES FOR SLIDER**

```
    <?php 
                    //or insert the ID of your fields Group.
                    $groupID='116';
                    $custom_field_keys = get_post_custom_keys($groupID);
                    foreach ( $custom_field_keys as $key => $fieldkey )
                    {
                        if (stristr($fieldkey,'field_'))
                        {
                            //echo $key . " => " . $fieldkey . "<br />";
                            //echo $field['label'] . ': ' . $field['value'];
                            //echo $fieldkey . "<br />";
                            $field = get_field_object($fieldkey, $groupID); 

                            $acf_field_name = $field['name'];

                            $attachment = get_field($acf_field_name);
                            echo "<img src='".$attachment['url']."' title='".$attachment['title']."'/>";


                        }
                    }

?>
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Just a note why this works: ACF uses wordpress-native custom post types and meta values ("post customs") :)

Comment: This is very complicated; see the answer by Lucas for a function already provided by ACF

Answer (score 8):

I'm surprised no one mentioned `acf_get_fields('someGroupId')` yet.

```
/**
 * acf_get_fields
 *
 * Returns and array of fields for the given $parent.
 *
 * @date    30/09/13
 * @since   5.0.0
 *
 * @param   (int|string|array) $parent The field group or field settings. Also accepts the field group ID or key.
 * @return  array
 */
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I was wondering why all other answers are so complex in comparison to `acf_get_fields`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a function I created to get a group's fields:

```
function my_acf_get_fields_in_group( $group_id ) {
    $acf_meta = get_post_custom( $group_id );
    $acf_fields = array();

    foreach ( $acf_meta as $key => $val ) {
        if ( preg_match( "/^field_/", $key ) ) {
            $acf_fields[$key] = $val;
        }
    }

    return $acf_fields;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone stumbled upon this page like I did, and tried to figure this out, these methods won't work anymore with Version 5 and above of Advanced Custom Fields as it's usings posts instead of postmeta.

In that environment, this is the way I was able to get fields from a group and use them as values for a select field:

```
function acf_load_select_choices( $field ) {

  global $wpdb;
  $group_slug = 'Name or slug of the group';

  $group_ID = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name =  '$group_slug' "); 
  if (empty($group_ID))
    $group_ID = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title =  '$group_slug' ");

  $field['choices'] = array();
  $fields = acf_get_fields_by_id($group_ID);

  // to see what $fields contains, use:
  echo '<pre>'.var_dump($fields).'</pre>';

  if( $fields ) {
    foreach( $fields as $fieldrow ) {
      $field['choices'][ $fieldrow['name'] ] = $fieldrow['label'];
    }
  }

  return $field;

}

add_filter('acf/load_field/name=selectfieldname', 'acf_load_select_choices');
```

Comment: `acf_get_fields_by_id` was **deprecated** in favor of new `acf_get_fields()`

Answer (score 1):

Since ACF uses custom posts of type 'acf' as groups, we can use get_page_by_title to retrieve the group's ID, and then do the rest. Here's a small utility function:

```
// This was tested with ACF free edition v4.4.11
function get_group_fields($group_name){
  $group = get_page_by_title($group_name, OBJECT, 'acf');
  if(empty($group)) return false;

  $meta = get_post_meta($group->ID);
  $acf_fields = array();

  foreach($meta as $key => $value){
    $acf_meta_key = stristr($key,'field_'); // acf fields all start with "field_"
    if($acf_meta_key) $acf_fields[] = get_field_object($key);
  }

  return $acf_fields; // returns an array of field objects
}
```

Usage:

```
$group_fields = get_group_fields('My marvelous group');

foreach($group_fields as $field){
   $label = $field['label'];
   $value = $field['value'];
   // etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still searching.
You can just do it like this:

```
<?php 

      $fields = get_field_objects();

      if( $fields )
      {
        foreach( $fields as $field_name => $field )
        {
            echo '<div>';
                echo '<h3>' . $field['label'] . '</h3>';
                echo $field['value'];
            echo '</div>';
        }
      }
?>
```

Comment: Please take a minute and explain what is going on in the code instead of dumping a code snippet.

Comment: Well, it just about the answer to the Question :
"how to get field names by their group."
And also a values in here;
The snippet is much self explanatory

Comment: Awesome! Don't know why they don't include `get_field_objects` in their documentation!

Comment: And how would we get the name of a certain field group instead of all?