# ACF: how do I get the fields and its values of a specific group?

Tags: php, functions, query, advanced-custom-fields, advanced-taxonomy-queries

```
        <?php $fields = acf_get_fields('6066'); 
        ?>

<?php if( $fields )
{ 
foreach( $fields as $field)
{
    $value = get_field( $field['name'] );

    if ($value) {
    
        echo '<dl>';
            echo '<dt>' . $field['label'] . '</dt>';
            echo '<dd>' . $field['value'] . '</dd>';
        echo '</dl>';
    }
} 

} 
?>
```

This is what I have. If I do a `var_dump` on `acf_get_fields`, it apparently sets the value to `NULL`. I could have known, as it's written here:

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field_object/

The problem: I have to first get all fields in a specific field_group, hence I am using `acf_get_fields`.

I thought with using `$field['value']` I could get it to work, but apparently this does not work.

**Can someone help me to retrieve the values in the foreach per field**? Surely there must be a way, right?

PS:

```
<?php 

$fields = get_fields();

if( $fields ): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach( $fields as $name => $value ): ?>
            <li><b><?php echo $name; ?></b> <?php echo $value; ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This gives me ALL fields. I just need a specific list of fields from a specific field group. That is the problem.

I tried all suggestions here: [ACF - get fields from group](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95126/acf-get-fields-from-group), but none of them do the trick for my case.

Answer (score 1):

```
$specifications_group_id = 6066; // ID of the your group as you mentioned 
$specifications_fields = array();

$fields = acf_get_fields( $specifications_group_id );

foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
    $field_value = get_field( $field['name'] );
    
    if ( $field_value && !empty( $field_value ) ) {
        $specifications_fields[$field['name']] = $field;
        $specifications_fields[$field['name']]['value'] = $field_value;
    }
}

print_r($specifications_fields );
```

Comment: Instead calling `get_field` for every field, you can use `get_fields` before foreach and look for field key in its result in the loop for performance.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it out and let you know!

Answer (score 1):

earlier I had to substitute fields from one post to another (related in the post object field) in the backend, but only for a specific group.
In my case this code worked

```
// Get field from another post
$another_post_id = get_field('Blocks-Benefits-copyBlock', $post_id );
$fields = acf_get_fields('group_6457959205b1b');
// Update fields in this post
foreach ($fields as $field) {
     $field_name = $field['name'];
     $field_value = get_field($field_name, $another_post_id);
     update_field($field_name, $field_value, $post_id);
     }
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it out and let you know!